# Using sed to get only the digits from all parameters to a bash script

Tags: bash

I need a help, please

I have script

```
#!/bin/bash
NUMBER=$(echo "$1" | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')  
echo $NUMBER
```

```
./test.sh tas1 tefst2 thgst3 ynft4 jhuf5 hjh6 jhd7   
1
```

returns only 1 but I need it 1234567

Comment: use `echo "$@" | sed ..` Good luck.

Comment: Add `set -x` to your script and observe why shellter's solution works.

Comment: You could, by the way, replace the script with `tr -cd [:digit:]` and pipe to it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for including a minimal example with code, how you run it, what you get and what you wanted. +1

Answer (score 6):

The reason you only get "1" is because `$1` is only the first parameter. Use `"$*"` to get a single string containing *all* the parameters, separated by spaces (by default).

You can also do this with bash variable substitution:

```
params="$*"
echo "${params//[^[:digit:]]/}"
```